# How to remove box outlines around parenthesis/brackets in TexStudio?

Tags: texstudio, highlighting, brackets, parenthesis, syntax-highlighting

As can be seen on the first image there are outlines around the brackets and parenthesis (blue and red colored), on the second picture is shown what happens to these outlines if I move away to another line ready to type. 
The blue boxes become solid black and the red become dotted black, but they are still there. They annoy me immensely and I would be grateful if someone would show me how to remove these box highlightings.

[image: Example of problem, not the red and blue boxes]

[image]

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I found the answer myself. These boxes are called placeholders. They can be removed by going to Options > Configure TexStudio. Then on the bottom left check Show Advanced Options. Go to the Completion tab on the left and in this tab uncheck Arguments as Placeholders on the top right. See the attached image.[image: example]

Comment: This removes the red boxes, but what about the text placeholders? like the `den` and `num` in `\dfrac{num}{den}`?

Comment: It has been a long time since I have used TexStudio, but as far as I remember, it solved the issue for me, if it doesn't remove all the placeholders im not sure. It's been too long since I have worked with TexStudio.

Comment: Thanks for this help. This was a very big eyesore for a very long time. BTW, I would like to know how did you change the color of those placeholders? I use a dark background for editor and those placeholders appear comepletely white. I have not been able to find any setting to change that color.

Comment: every time I install texstudio on new PC, I spend at least one hr finding and unchecking all such stupid annoying configuration settings to clear everything. I have no idea why they do this, May be just to annoy people.

Answer (score 18):

The boxes are placeholders. You can navigate between them using `Ctrl+Left/Right`.

They vanish, if you type over them e.g. if the cursor is before a closing bracket placeholder `)`, typing `)` will move the cursor past and remove the placeholder.

You can also use `Idefix -> Remove Placeholder (Ctrl+Shift+K)`.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the additional explanation :)

Comment: The problem is the damn thing never properly disappear once cursor is somewhere else. But +1 for that shortcut!